# Executing JavaScript in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to execute some JavaScript via Puppeteer, which I'd normally execute through the Dev Tools console, as below:

[Dev Tools Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pns6O.png)

Essentially I'm trying to list out all the elements in the Array.

I've been reading through StackOverflow and the Docs here:

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args

But I can't seem to get this working. I've tried evaluating the page with a multitude of different bits of code, all have come up empty.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a small but complete code example for the puppeteer with this problem?

Comment: Thanks @vsemozhetbyt, I answered my own question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I suspected, this was extremely simple code.

I'd actually already written this code prior to asking this question, but I'd written it within the wrong section of the overall script and thus threw an error.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(<URL>)
​
  const ids = await page.evaluate('product_ids');
​
  console.log('ids are:', ids);
​
  await browser.close();
 })();
```